# Running jar file of Spring batch application in background in centos with input arguments

Tags: java, centos, executable-jar

Iam trying to run a spring batch application jar file in background in centos with input arguments. nohup java -Dserver.port=8881 -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar Batch-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar​ &. Iam getting nohup: ignoring input and appending out to nohup.out and my application is not running. someone please provide a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is,  nohup: ignoring input and appending out to nohup.out is saying that, it had started the service and printing the terminal message to nohout file. If I open the nohup.out file, it was saying a code level issue. After Fixing that, i could see my service running. To check active running jar, type jps -m. To kill the process Kill $PID {{PID}}